# Kivy for Python 3 on a Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, version, kivy

I was wondering if `kivy` supports Python 3 on Mac OS X systems. From the [download](http://kivy.org/#download) page from the `kivy` official website, it seems that `kivy-1.9.0` is available for Python 3.4 for Windows systems, but it does not seem to support Python 3 on Mac OS X:

> Mac OS X Mac OS X 10.9, 10.10 (requires Python 2.7)
>   Kivy-1.9.0-rev3-osx.dmg (Mirror)

This seems a little but nonsensical, why kivy should support Python 3 on Windows but not on a Mac OS X? It could be because of the missing support of PyGame for Python 3 for OS X systems? Actually, there's a way to install PyGame for OS X systems for Python 3, so I do not understand why they do not fix this problem, if this is really a problem.

I have also tried to install it globally via `pip3` using:

```
sudo pip3 install kivy
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Collecting kivy   Downloading Kivy-1.9.0.tar.gz (16.2MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 16.2MB 34kB/s 
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>
> ```
> Cython is missing, its required for compiling kivy !
>
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
>   File "/private/tmp/pip-build-qt70t_44/kivy/setup.py", line 173, in <module>
>     from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
> ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
>
> ----------------------------------------
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-qt70t_44/kivy
> ```

Comment: I'm not certain here, but I think the package supports python2 because it uses the system installation. I could be wrong though, someone else may know for sure. You should be able to install it yourself if you make sure you have the dependencies, particularly sdl2 now (not pygame any more). In this case, it seems you lack cython...I don't know how you installed python, but you'll need to install cython if you want to compile kivy.

Comment: I installed Python from the PSF website... I didn't know `cython` was a dependency, but the error is of course related to it...Do you know a guide to install kivy for Python by installing all the dependencies?

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @toine I had given up using Kivy (this question is from 3 months ago) and for now I will not try to use it again, because I don't have time. In a few days I will try and I make you know ;)

Comment: @inclement Kivy comes with its own python distribution. It might work with the system installation but that is not its default.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to [build from source](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html#os-x).

As a previous poster mentioned, you will need to get Cython installed.

To get the latest version, use

```
$ pip3 install cython
```

From there, you need to modify setup.py. [Here's an example of how I did it.](https://github.com/uclatommy/kivy/wiki/Building-for-OSX-Python3)

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, you are missing the package `cython`:

```
Cython is missing, its required for compiling kivy !
...
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
```

You should run `pip install cython`.
Then installing from source worked for me, by opposition to using `pip`.